# Unable to serve static asset (jpg) when using app.use(middleware)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have a middleware which is called everytime a request is made towards my Express appplication:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
   if(req.isAuthenticated()) return next();

   return response.redirect('/login');
})
```

And for the login page, I am serving a simple ejs file with a click to login button and a background image of computer as such.

[image]

The issue is, when I am using that said middleware and if the user is not authenticated, the static file which is the background, won't be served. Everything else shows up though. I need the middleware for authentication purposes but it doesn't serve the file if the user does a fresh open on the app (means the user is not logged in). How can I serve the asset while keeping this middleware?

Answer (score 0):

There's typically no reason why you'd want to force authentication on static assets (and besides, your middleware is only meant to catch unauthenticated requests made to regular pages, not image/js/css-files), so don't declare your middleware until after the middleware that serves the static assets is declared:

```
app.use(express.static(...));

app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
   if(req.isAuthenticated()) return next();

   return response.redirect('/login');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the idea that do not require authentication when accessing static resources, but if you really want to do so, of course you can, just do the following:

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        express.static(...)(req, res, next);
    }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
})
```